# Updating of GNU screen's hardstatus hostname

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, hostname

According to the [Gnu screen user's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/String-Escapes.html), one can set the "hostname of the system" with `hardstatus string "%H"`.

Changing via `ssh` into another system while in a screen session, the hostname is *not* updated in the hardstatus line.

**My questions:**

1. Is this intentional behaviour?
2. If yes, what is the philosophy behind that?
3. How can I set the hardstatus line to show the current machine?

To my understanding, this behaviour is only appropriate when using nested screen sessions *and* when the remote machine has the hostname in its hardstatus, too. Then it is possible to see the "tree" of the screen sessions.

In all other cases, the relevant information is the *current* hostname, not the one where the screen session originally started with. That is in my eyes redundant since I know perfectly well at which machine I sit at the moment…

To solve this, I tried to conjure an update of the hostname every second through the backtick command

```
backtick 1 1 1 hostname
hardstatus alwayslastline "%1`"
```

but the original hostname was still persistant.

Although I found many sites providing different and sometimes complex gnu screen configuration files ([1](https://debian-administration.org/article/560/An_introduction_to_the_visual_features_of_GNU_Screen),
[2](https://gist.github.com/joaopizani/2718397),
[3](https://mreschke.com/68/linux-screen-command),
[4](https://serverfault.com/a/621939)) with colorful and informative hardstatus lines,
none addresses the current hostname except [this one](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-users/2008-07/msg00016.html). There it was in the context of automatically connecting to another machine and updating the windows title, which is not what I am after.

Comment: `screen` runs on one system; it doesn't know what fancy "ssh" commands you're running inside of it, which is probably why you see workarounds to (re)set it.

Comment: The hostname is only captured when you start `screen`; it doesn't check if you change the hostname while it's running.  Feature requests should be addressed to screen's developers.